# How to create an msi from a Windows Forms project?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

I am trying to create an installer for a project which I recently completed. I also used a database(SQL Server Compact), but I don't know much about how to do it. I've read some articles on MSDN, but they weren't clear to me.